# Update long from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I Have been trying to update long from firebase database but each time I do it gives me an error... This is my Firebase Database: [image: groups firebase database]

```
mDatabaseGroup.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            final String team_a = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Team_A").child("team_name").getValue();
            final long team_ad = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Team_A").child("d").getValue();
            final long team_al = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Team_A").child("l").getValue();
            final long team_ap = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Team_A").child("p").getValue();
            final long team_aw = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Team_A").child("w").getValue();
            final long team_apts = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Team_A").child("pts").getValue();
            final String team_b = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Team_B").child("team_name").getValue();
            final long team_bd = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Team_B").child("d").getValue();
            final long team_bl = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Team_B").child("l").getValue();
            final long team_bp = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Team_B").child("p").getValue();
            final long team_bw = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Team_B").child("w").getValue();
            final long team_bpts = (long) dataSnapshot.child("Team_B").child("pts").getValue();
            final String team_c = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Team_C").child("team_name").getValue();
            String team_d = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Team_D").child("team_name").getValue();}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This is the error I'm faced with:

ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

This is my stackTrace:

> 

```
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x56944ba8 sslWrite buf=0x427180f8 len=99 write_timeout_millis=0
D/NativeCrypto:  sslNotify, appData=0x5807ff10 ret=1
D/NativeCrypto:  sslSelect, appData=0x5807ff10 woken up by a token
D/NativeCrypto:  sslSelect, appData=0x5807ff10 read ret=1 
D/SQLiteDatabase: beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4187ece0)
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
W/System.err:     at com.example.zack.admin.ViewFixtureActivity$1.onDataChange(ViewFixtureActivity.java:85)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaih.zza(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajh.zzctc(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajk$1.run(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.zack.admin, PID: 26018
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
                      at com.example.zack.admin.ViewFixtureActivity$1.onDataChange(ViewFixtureActivity.java:85)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaih.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajh.zzctc(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajk$1.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

If anyone knows another way of updating long on firebase, it's also welcome.

Comment: Have you check any of value have string data and you are type cast with string ?

Because of according to error, you are parsing any data which have string and you are convert directly to string.

Please refer get data with POJO class that's better option for parsing data in object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a single value with type long (i.e., /Groups/-Kh2GRPKiuQdePCubLi0/A/Team_A/d), you may code like below:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Groups/-Kh2GRPKiuQdePCubLi0/A/Team_A/d").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Long team_ad = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

If read from reference (Groups/-Kh2GRPKiuQdePCubLi0/A), you may code like below:

```
// Create a model class for your dataSnapshot
public static class Team {
    public long d;
    public long l;
    public long p;
    public long pts;
    public String team_name;
    public long w;

    public Team() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Team.class)
    }
}
// Read from database
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Groups/-Kh2GRPKiuQdePCubLi0/A").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot childDataSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Team team = childDataSnapShot.getValue(Team.class);
                switch (childDataSnapShot.getKey())
                {
                    case "Team_A":
                        final String team_a = team.team_name;
                        final long team_ad = team.d;
                        final long team_al = team.l;
                        final long team_ap = team.p;
                        final long team_aw = team.w;
                        final long team_apts = team.pts;
                        break;
                    case "Team_B":
                        final String team_b = team.team_name;
                        final long team_bd = team.d;
                        final long team_bl = team.l;
                        final long team_bp = team.p;
                        final long team_bw = team.w;
                        final long team_bpts = team.pts;
                        break;
                    case "Team_C":
                        final String team_c = team.team_name;
                        final long team_cd = team.d;
                        final long team_cl = team.l;
                        final long team_cp = team.p;
                        final long team_cw = team.w;
                        final long team_cpts = team.pts;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Team failed, log a message
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "loadTeam:onCancelled ", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_and_write_data

Answer (score 0):

use `String.valueOf()` in the place if casting with `(String)`

`String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Team_C").child("team_name").getValue());`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it gives me this error:  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure your DatabaseReference `mDatabaseGroup` is at the correct location of `/Groups/Key/A`, so that you are getting the correct values from the database.

Secondly, try

```
final long team_ad = dataSnapshot.child("Team_A").child("d").getValue(Long.class);
```